# JavaScript Regex get multiple single quotation marks inside single quotation marks in a SQL insert

Tags: javascript, sql, regex, migration

**Problem**

I am doing a database migration and I came across the following senario, I have single quotation mark inside the single quotation marks of the insert and after several attempts to fix I reached the conclusion that I would need to use regex and I arrived to the point where I could replace the single quotation mark in the center of the text, I now have a problem when it appears at the beginning. my regex has the first two single quotation mark but my goal is the last two.

SQL Insert:

```
(1, '22', '2006-11-10', '3', 'field1', 'field2', '2006-12-12', '11:20:06', '''field3', '

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ex ipsum, luctus id dignissim tempor, volutpat eget sapien. Cras accumsan molestie iaculis. Mauris vehicula a nunc vel tincidunt. 
 Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 

    - Lorem ipsum dolor '' sit amet - ''''

 Aliquam vestibulum tincidunt odio, id varius sapien lacinia ac. Phasellus ullamcorper ante ut lacus dictum commodo.
  Integer sit amet lacus ornare massa feugiat tempus. 

', null, null);
```

My Regex(js):

```
((["'])(?:(?=(\'\'\?))\2)*?)\1(?!,)
```

My goal after regexp and make a find and replace is to have this as a result:

```
(1, '22', '2006-11-10', '3', 'field1', 'field2', '2006-12-12', '11:20:06', '\'\'field3', '

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ex ipsum, luctus id dignissim tempor, volutpat eget sapien. Cras accumsan molestie iaculis. Mauris vehicula a nunc vel tincidunt. 
 Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 

    - Lorem ipsum dolor \'\' sit amet - \'\'\'\'

 Aliquam vestibulum tincidunt odio, id varius sapien lacinia ac. Phasellus ullamcorper ante ut lacus dictum commodo.
  Integer sit amet lacus ornare massa feugiat tempus. 

', null, null);
```

I am using this site to test: https://regex101.com/ (with javascript selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to match a `'` or `"` delimiter, then lazy-repeat until you match that delimiter again *followed by a comma* (or a `)`, in case the item is the last in the list).  Then, use a replacer function to replace everything inside the delimiters with `'`s escaped:

```js
const input = `(1, '22', '2006-11-10', '3', 'field1', 'field2', '2006-12-12', '11:20:06', '''field3', '

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ex ipsum, luctus id dignissim tempor, volutpat eget sapien. Cras accumsan molestie iaculis. Mauris vehicula a nunc vel tincidunt. 
 Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 

    - Lorem ipsum dolor '' sit amet - ''''

 Aliquam vestibulum tincidunt odio, id varius sapien lacinia ac. Phasellus ullamcorper ante ut lacus dictum commodo.
  Integer sit amet lacus ornare massa feugiat tempus. 

', null, null);`;


const output = input.replace(
  /(["'])([\s\S]*?)\1(?=[,)])/g,
  (_, delim, content) => delim + content.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + delim
);
console.log(output);
```

https://regex101.com/r/RRmq8g/1

If you want to escape `"`s like that when the delimiters are `"`, then construct the replacer regex from the `delim`:

```
const output = input.replace(
  /(["'])([\s\S]*?)\1(?=[,)])/g,
  (_, delim, content) => {
    const pattern = new RegExp(delim, 'g')
    return delim + content.replace(pattern, '\\' + delim) + delim
  }
);
```

```js
const input = `(1, "22 foo bar "double quotes" here ", '2006-11-10', '3', 'field1', 'field2', '2006-12-12', '11:20:06', '''field3', '

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ex ipsum, luctus id dignissim tempor, volutpat eget sapien. Cras accumsan molestie iaculis. Mauris vehicula a nunc vel tincidunt. 
 Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 

    - Lorem ipsum dolor '' sit amet - ''''

 Aliquam vestibulum tincidunt odio, id varius sapien lacinia ac. Phasellus ullamcorper ante ut lacus dictum commodo.
  Integer sit amet lacus ornare massa feugiat tempus. 

', null, null);`;


const output = input.replace(
  /(["'])([\s\S]*?)\1(?=[,)])/g,
  (_, delim, content) => {
    const pattern = new RegExp(delim, 'g')
    return delim + content.replace(pattern, '\\' + delim) + delim
  }
);
console.log(output);
```

`/(["'])([\s\S]*?)\1(?=[,)])/g` means:

- `(["'])` Match and capture a delimiter
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Repeat any character, until you get to:
- `\1` - The delimiter, followed by
- `(?=[,)])` - either a comma, or a `)`